# Django social auth error logging in with two email accounts

Tags: python, django, email, google-oauth, django-socialauth

My application must be accessed through an account like **user@mydomain.com** (Google managed email account)

First time I launch my application I can log in normally using that account.
The problem starts when I log out (django log out) and try to login with my Gmail account (This is not allowed because of my email verification pipeline)

The first account is my **user@mydomain.com** and the second is my **user@gmail.com** account

[image: Email accounts]

I have a pipeline to verify if the user email belongs to my domain

Clicking on the **@gmail.com** account return an error from my pipeline

```
@partial
def require_mydomain_email(strategy, details, user=None, is_new=False, *args, **kwargs):
    if user and user.email:
        if '@mydomain' in user.email:
            return
    elif is_new and not details.get('email'):
        email = strategy.request_data().get('email')
        if email:
            details['email'] = email
        else:
            current_partial = kwargs.get('current_partial')
            return strategy.redirect(
                '/email?partial_token={0}'.format(current_partial.token)
            )
    else:
        email = details.get('email')
        if email:
            if '@mydomain' in email:
                return
        else:
            current_partial = kwargs.get('current_partial')
            messages.add_message(strategy.request, messages.WARNING, 'Your email must be an @mydomain email')
            return strategy.redirect('/'.format(current_partial.token))
```

The Main problem:

After trying to log in with **gmail.com** account doesn't matter what account I'm trying to login after, my backend always receives the **@gmail** data from google.

Here are my pipeline settings:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social_core.pipeline.mail.mail_validation',
    'accounts.google_authentication.pipeline.require_psafe_email',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.debug.debug',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details',
    'social_core.pipeline.debug.debug'
)
```

Any thoughts that may be helpful?

Edit1:

param details from my pipeline after run application (replaced personal data):

```
{'fullname': 'My Name', 'email': 'user@mydomain', 'first_name': 'Name', 'username': 'user.name', 'last_name': 'LastName'}
```

Then I log out,try to log in with my @gmail account (for testing porpuses):

```
{'fullname': 'My Full Name', 'email': 'myuser@gmail.com', 'first_name': 'MyName', 'username': 'username', 'last_name': 'Last Name'}
```

And even if I try to log in with **user@mydomain.com** again, I receive **@gmail** data

Comment: What happens if you define `SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_AUTH_EXTRA_ARGUMENTS = { 'prompt': 'select_account' }`?

Comment: same error.
what is strange is that when I look in my social-auth-partil table, it shows info like this:

{"kwargs": {"uid": "myemail@gmail.com", "details": {"username": "gmailusername, "first_name": "Name", "fullname": "My Full Name", "last_name": "Last Name", "email": "myemail@gmail.com"}, "social": null, "user": null, "username": "username91a8483897684742", "is_new": true, "request": {"hd": ["companydomain.com"]

in the end, on the "request" key there is an "companydomain.com
The company domain is correct, but the email returned is my personal gmail

Comment: @omab Thank you! Setting `SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_AUTH_EXTRA_ARGUMENTS` was the setting that fixed this for me. I can't find that setting documented anywhere - neither https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io nor https://github.com/python-social-auth . Am I missing something? How did you know about it?